# Select dropdown list doesn't save selected option - asp.net core web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, html-select

I'm trying to save data on a table but for some reason the Select element of Html always saves the first DateTime option item instead of saving the one I selected.

Here I select the option corresponding to the date highlighted but when I save the information the first option (22-01-08) is the one that it´s saved on the database table

[image: DropDown]

[image: Database]

My View Model:

```
public class BookNowViewModel
{
    public string FilmeName { get; set; }      
    public DateTime FilmeDate { get; set; }
    public string seatNum { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int FilmeId { get; set;  }  
}
```

My Controller where i set the functions do save the data retrieved from the view to the "Cart" table:

```
[HttpGet]
public  IActionResult BookNow(int Id)
{
    BookNowViewModel vm = new BookNowViewModel();
    var item =  _context.Filme.Where(a => a.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
    var it = _context.Sessao.Where(n => n.FilmeId == Id).FirstOrDefault();
    vm.FilmeName = item.Name;
    vm.FilmeDate = it.Date;
    vm.FilmeId = Id;
    vm.Price = Convert.ToInt32(item.Price);

    ViewBag.FilmeDate = _context.Sessao.Where(a => a.FilmeId == Id)
             .Select(i => new SelectListItem
             {
                 Value = i.Id.ToString(),
                 Text = i.Date.ToString()
             }).ToList();

    return  View(vm);
}
    
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> BookNow(BookNowViewModel vm,int Id)
{   
    List<Cart> carts = new List<Cart>();
    string seatNum = vm.seatNum.ToString();
    int filmeId = vm.FilmeId;
    var filme = _context.Filme.Where(a => a.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
    var sessao = _context.Sessao.Where(n => n.FilmeId == Id).FirstOrDefault();

    string[] seatNumArray = seatNum.Split(",");
    count = seatNumArray.Length;

    if (checkSeat(seatNum, filmeId) == false)
    {
        foreach (var item in seatNumArray)
        {
            carts.Add(new Cart
            {
                Price = Convert.ToInt32(filme.Price),
                MovieId = vm.FilmeId,
                UserId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User),
                Date = sessao.Date,
                seatNum = item
            });;
        }
        foreach (var item in carts)
        {
            _context.Cart.Add(item);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            //_context.SaveChanges();
        }
  
    TempData["Sucess"] = "Seat Booked, See your Cart";
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["seatnummsg"] = "Please Change you seat number";
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");            
}
```

My View :

```
div class="col-md-4">
<form asp-action="BookNow" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FilmeName" class="control-label"></label>
        @Model.FilmeName
        <span asp-validation-for="FilmeName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FilmeDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <select name="ok" id="FilmeDate" asp-for="FilmeDate" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.FilmeDate"></select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="seatNum" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="seatNum" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="seatNum" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FilmeId" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="FilmeId" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="FilmeId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-default btn-success text-white" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

I can see a couple of issues here.

The `<select>` element has the wrong `name` attribute. You can remove `name="ok"` (and the id) as the tag-helper `asp-for` will automatically set the `name` and `id` attributes. It should correctly bind to the `FilmeDate` property if you change it to:

```
<select asp-for="FilmeDate" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.FilmeDate"></select>
```

You're populating the ViewBag with dates, but you're assigning the value to the `Id` not the Date. Use the date in the value field too:

```
...
    .Select(i => new SelectListItem
     {
         Value = i.Date.ToString(),
         Text = i.Date.ToString()
     }
```

However, another problem is that you're not using the value from the viewmodel when saving to the database. It looks like you're saving a value which you just read from the database: `Date = sessao.Date`. You should use the value from the ViewModel: `Date = vm.FilmeDate`.

```
...
    // only 1 for loop required
    foreach (var item in seatNumArray)
    {
        var cart = new Cart
        {    
            Price = Convert.ToInt32(filme.Price),
            MovieId = vm.FilmeId,
            UserId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User),
            Date = vm.FilmeDate, // use the value selected the viewmodel
            seatNum = item
        };
        _context.Cart.Add(cart);                        
    }
    // save changes after adding all items
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

You only need a single loop and you can save changes after adding all items too. Since you're no longer using `sessao` in the Post method it can be removed.

Aside: if you're checking for seat availability for a particular film in `checkSeat(seatNum, filmeId)`, you may also need to consider the film date too.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the tips you provided make sense but after making these changes the DateTime is saved in my cart table as a default value (01/01/0001 00:00:00) and not the option I choose

Comment: I think there's also a problem with the  HTML for the `<select>` element.  You should remove `name="ok"` - which sets the name to bind to "ok".  The tag helper will set the name. It should be: `<select asp-for="FilmeDate" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.FilmeDate"></select>` (you can remove the id too) @CodingInPyjama

Comment: @CodingInPyjama,asp .net core bind data with `name` attribute.