# Delete post method returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am following a beginner tutorial on how to make a simple store with asp.net mvc, and in tutorial there is no problem when doing exact same steps.
I am currently trying to perform a basic CRUD operations on my category page, but i am stuck when trying to delete categories. I get not found page because id is null, but i don't have problem  for Edit method when passing the same id parameter.
I was looking for an answer and some people suggest that there might be caching problem, but not sure how to even try to fix that.
Here is my controller for delete operations

```
 // GET-DELETE
        public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            
            if (id == null || id == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Category obj = _db.Category.Find(id);

         if (obj == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(obj);
        }

        //POST-DELETE
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

        public IActionResult DeletePost(int? id)
        {
            Category obj = _db.Category.Find(id);

            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            
            
            _db.Category.Remove(obj);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
           
           
        }
```

and here is my View

```
@model RockyWebsite.Models.Category

<form method="post" asp-action="DeletePost">
    @Html.HiddenFor(id => id.CategoryId)
    <input asp-for="CategoryId" hidden />

    <div class="border p-3">

        <div class="form-group row">
            <h2 class="text-info pl-3">Delete Category</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="CategoryName"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="CategoryName" disabled class="form-control" />

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="DisplayOrder"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="DisplayOrder" disabled class="form-control" />

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-8 offset-4 row">

                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger w-100" value="Delete" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success w-100"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                @* Keep this empty *@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Any help or suggestion would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

add name tag to input, for example :

```
<input name="id" asp-for="CategoryId" hidden />
```

Alex

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `name=` and `asp-for=` on the same control because it could introduce bugs such as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70718755/select-dropdown-list-doesnt-save-selected-option-asp-net-core-web-app). I would manually create the control in this case to reduce the chance of future bugs `<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="@Model.CategoryId" />`

Comment: yes, you can use hidden input also

Answer (score 0):

You're using `@Html.HiddenFor(id => id.CategoryId)` (well, you're actually using the tag-helper syntax too `<input asp-for="CategoryId" hidden />` and you should just use one or the other, not both!) in the view which will create an input with `name="CategoryId"`.

So, the easiest solution is probably to correct the view and update the parameter name in the controller action for `DeletePost`.

View:

```html
<!-- remove this line: @Html.HiddenFor(id => id.CategoryId) -->
<!-- just use line below -->
<input type="hidden" asp-for="CategoryId" />
```

Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult DeletePost(int? categoryId)
{
    Category obj = _db.Category.Find(categoryId);
    // check obj here, not id
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }    
    
    _db.Category.Remove(obj);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your form tag with this one

```
@Html.BeginForm("DeletePost", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post,
 new {id="@Model.CategoryId"})
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

and action

```
[HttpPost("{id}")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult DeletePost(int id)
```